# Avoiding Duplicates Responses in table - laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I have template which displays two questions for my 3 (three)clients to respond to. As seen in the Response below, it duplicates the question to show each and every clients answer.

But what i want to have is, group similar answers below with their count. How can i do this please?  Thanks for your help in advance.

**Template Question**

```
1. How would you describe our products and services?

2. Overall, how satisfied or dissatisfied are your with our company?
```

Now when clients respond to the questions it is shown in my view like

**Response**

```
                        Question                          Answers

 How would you describe our products and services?     -  Reliable

 How would you describe our products and services?     -  Expensive

 How would you describe our products and services?     -  Reliable



   Overall, how satisfied or dissatisfied are your with - Satisfied
   our company?

   Overall, how satisfied or dissatisfied are your with - Satisfied
   our company?

   Overall, how satisfied or dissatisfied are your with - Dissatisfied
   our company?
```

**What i want**

```
                        Question                          Answers

 How would you describe our products and services?     -  Reliable  (2)
                                                          Expensive (1)

 Overall, how satisfied or dissatisfied are your with - Satisfied    (2)
   our company?                                       - Dissatisfied (1)
```

**Controller**

```
 public function view_survey_answers(Survey $survey) 
  {
     $survey->load('user.questions.answers');
    return view('answer.ans', compact('survey'));
  }
```

**answer.ans**

```
   <table class="bordered striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id">Question</th>
        <th  data-field="ans">Answer(s)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    @forelse ($survey->questions as $item)
    @foreach ($item->answers as $answer)
    <tr>
      <td width="30%">{{ $item->title }}</td>                
     <td  width="40%" >{{$answer->answer}}</td>    
    </tr>
    @endforeach    
    @empty
      <tr>
        <td>
          No answers provided by you for this Survey
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    @endforelse
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Question**

```
class Question extends Model
{
  protected $casts = [
      'option_name' => 'array',
  ];
  protected $fillable = ['title', 'question_type', 'option_name', 'user_id'];
  public function survey() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
  }

  public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  public function answers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
  }

  public function count_answers() 
  {    
    return $this->select(‘answers’, DB::raw('count(*) as counter'))->answers()->groupBy(‘answers’)->get();  

  }

  protected $table = 'question';

}
```

**Answer**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Answer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['answers'];
    protected $table = 'answer';

    public function survey() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
    }

    public function question() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }

    public function customers(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_phone','phone');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Introduce a new function in your Question model

   ```
   public function count_answers() {    
       return $this—>select(‘answers’, DB::raw('count(*) as counter'))->answers()->groupBy(‘answers’)->get();  
   }
   ```
2. Edit the view

```html
 <table class="bordered striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id">Question</th>
        <th  data-field="ans">Answer(s)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    @forelse ($survey->questions as $item)
    <tr>
      <td width="30%">{{ $item->title }}</td>
<td  width="40%" >                
    @foreach ($item->count_answers as $answer)
     <div>{{$answer->answer}} ({{$answer->counter}})</div>
    @endforeach    
</td>
    </tr>
    @empty
      <tr>
        <td>
          No answers provided by you for this Survey
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    @endforelse
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Call to undefined function App\select() in my Question model

Comment: I've modified the order of the query. You can check it out.

Comment: `Use of undefined constant ‘answers’ - assumed '‘answers’' ` is the error i get.  I will add my model above for Question and Answers

Comment: the issue seems to be from my view. when i took out  `@foreach ($item->count_answers as $answer)
     <div>{{$answer->answer}} ({{$answer->counter}})</div>
    @endforeach `,  there is no error

Comment: Perhaps check the group by field 'answers' in the query. Is that correct in your table?